# Huge delay in ps output from systemd in Azure Linux

Tags: systemd, ps, delay

I'm getting huge a delay in ps output -- when it outputs the first line (`systemd-networkd`), there is a huge delay about **20** to **25** seconds, then the rest are displayed instantly.

```
$ ps -eaf
. . .
systemd+ 31865     1  0 Jul22 ?        00:00:10 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
62583    31891     1  0 Jul22 ?        00:00:12 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
root     31922     1  0 Jul22 ?        00:02:09 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
. . .
```

Any idea why (and the fix)?

```
$ time ps -o uname -p 31891
USER
62583

real    0m25.025s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.006s

$ time getent passwd 62583 | wc
      0       0       0

real    0m25.030s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.001s

$ grep 62583 /etc/passwd | wc 
      0       0       0

$ grep passwd /etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd:         compat systemd

$ grep compat /etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd:         compat systemd
group:          compat systemd
shadow:         compat

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

$ uname -rm
5.4.0-1047-azure x86_64
```

Comment: `passwd` is set to `compat systemd`.  That implies that it is allowed to use NIS/NIS+ in some cases.  If you don't think those are in use, then this setting is odd.  Maybe you ran a command that enabled it in the past? Could try changing that to `passwd:  files` to turn it off.  Also, look to see if you have `compat` as a key in nsswitch.conf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suspicion is that `ps` is trying to turn the numeric UID into a username, doing a lookup for that UID, then timing out.   After the failed lookup, the numeric ID is displayed.

See if these two commands show a difference:

`ps -o uid -p 31891`

`ps -o uname -p 31891`

Now why would it be doing that lookup and timing out?  Could you have NIS configured for usernames? What do you have for `grep passwd /etc/nsswitch.conf`?  You could check your lookup via `getent passwd 62583`, but I imagine that it will be blank.

To fix:

If you don't think you are using NIS/NIS+ as an information system (and this would be *very* unusual for a single system), then you could turn this off by changing the line in nsswitch.conf to

`passwd:  files`

telling the resolver that only the local file (/etc/passwd) is to be used for account information.  Can be changed back if it breaks something.

Comment: Bingo! You hit the nail right on the head sir, see my updated OP to confirm your conclusions. Now the problem is, just as you asked, _"why would it be doing that"_? This is just a standalone Azure Linux VM created by MS Azure using everything default a while back, and I didn't touch anything on the configuration side. Any idea how it can be fixed? Thx

Comment: Bingo again! Thanks a lot for the fix! Spot on!! I fixed both the `passwd:` and `group:` FTR, see my updates in OP.